# C++ vector error (Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition)

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run this small program in `Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition`:

```
#include <vector>
int main(){
vector<bool> features(4,false);
for(vector<bool>::iterator i = features.begin(); i != features.end(); i++){
cout<<features[i];
}
}
```

When I do that I get the following:

```
   1>------ Build started: Project: SFS, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>SFS.cpp
1>.\SFS.cpp(1) : warning C4627: '#include <vector>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>        Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>.\SFS.cpp(14) : fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Ola\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SFS\SFS\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>SFS - 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I also get the following error message:

[image]

**EDIT(1)**

After I add `#include "stdafx.h"`, I get the following:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SFS, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>SFS.cpp
1>.\SFS.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'vector' : undeclared identifier
1>.\SFS.cpp(5) : error C2062: type 'bool' unexpected
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'vector' : undeclared identifier
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2062: type 'bool' unexpected
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2039: 'iterator' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'features' : undeclared identifier
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is ''unknown-type''
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
1>.\SFS.cpp(6) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>.\SFS.cpp(7) : error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
1>.\SFS.cpp(7) : error C2065: 'features' : undeclared identifier
1>.\SFS.cpp(7) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Ola\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SFS\SFS\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>SFS - 15 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

In addition to the same error message box.

**EDIT(2)**

After I add `#include<iostream>` and use `std::cout`, I get the following:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SFS, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>SFS.cpp
1>.\SFS.cpp(1) : warning C4627: '#include <iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>        Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>.\SFS.cpp(2) : warning C4627: '#include <vector>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>        Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>.\SFS.cpp(16) : fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Ola\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SFS\SFS\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>SFS - 1 error(s), 2 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

In addition to the same error message box.

Why is that? How can I solve this out?

Thanks.

Comment: The error mentiones precompiled headers. Please turn them off in your project and rebuild

Comment: If I consider your posted code is compelet content of SFS.cpp, I would add "#include <iostream>" and swap "cout" with "std::cout".

Comment: See edited answer. Also, please refrain from making major changes to your question. Ask a different one for a different problem.

Comment: @PoweRoy. How can I turn off the precompiled headers off? Thanks

Comment: @Med-SWEng What is the type of your project you have created in Visual Studio? Try to add empty project maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Weird MSVS stuff. Is the first file you include `"stdafx.h"`? It should be.

Also, do a clean build (rebuild or clean/build).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
int main(){
vector<bool> features(4,false);
for(vector<bool>::iterator i = features.begin(); i != features.end(); i++){
cout<<features[i];
}
}
```

or you can turn off the option to build using precompiled headers in the project properties.

You also need:

```
#include <vector>
```

and replace `vector` with `std::vector`.

Comment: How can I turn off the option to build using precompiled headers in the project properties? Thanks

Comment: @Med-SWEng you don't need to, just include stdafx.h

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer maybe, but this works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<bool> features(4,false);
    for(std::vector<bool>::iterator i = features.begin(); i != features.end(); i++){
        std::cout<< (*i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<bool> features(4,false);
    for(vector<bool>::iterator i = features.begin(); i != features.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << *i;
    }
}
```

Under VS2010 you can turn off precompiled headers under the project properties C/C++ subsection, precompilers subsection.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. I used

```
#include <vector>
```

also `std::vector`, rather than `vector`, but the problem is still there. later, I tried to add the following line:

```
using namespace std;
```

and all the errors gone!

I wondered why? finally, I figured out when I defined a two dimensional vector, I used: `std::vector<vector<double>> myVector;`, which should be:     `std::vector<std::vector<double>> myvector;` if the `std` namespace is not specified.